# Firebase Security Rules allow if datafield is less than x

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have an Events collection and a Users collection. My Event page increments a counter (in Users collection) when an event is uploaded. I want to limit the number of events per user to 10.
This what I have so far and it doesn't seem to work as expected:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/collection/Events{
    allow read;
    allow write: if 50 > 
    get(/databases/collection/Users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.numberOfEvents;
  }
}
```

//Tried this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  // Do not change this
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

     // Path to your document
     match /Users/{doc=**} {
     allow read;
     allow write;
     }
    match /Events/{doc=**} { 
        allow read;
      allow write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/Users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.numberOfEvents < 50;
    }
  }
}
```

Actually the last one seems to work, let me test some more, thanks for all help!
It seems to work! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are not specifying the document path correct. Assuming events and users are both root level collections. Try the following rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  // Do not change this
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

     // Path to your document - collection names are case sensitive
    match /events/{eventId} { 
      allow write: if get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.numberOfEvents < 10;
    }
  }
}
```

You should however not allow users to write to `numberOfEvents` directly from client as they can reduce the number and try to add more events. [Firestore triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events) for Cloud functions might be useful here to increment/decrement the value securely from backend.

Comment: This doesn't work either, now it doesn't permit any uploads at all despite the count being below limit.

Comment: @Sondre please share structure of your firstore and your code in that case first

Comment: Event path is this /Events/078l2ssrXXyAiYV3MlSs but it doesn't matter what the eventID is as each user can create many events.
User path is Users/(same UserID as firebase-auth ID)

Comment: @Sondre collection names and doc ID are case sensitive. If your collection name is "Events" with capital E then it should be same in rules `match /Events/{eventId}` and you need to define rules for users collection separately. By default any ops are rejected

Comment: @Sondre you should use `match /Events/{docId}` if you want to limit the rule to that collection only instead of `match /Events/{doc=**}` the recursive wildcard that'll apply rule to all sub-collections as well.